# Accessing the contents of My Contents folder using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to populate a dropdown menu with a list of the items in the My Contents folder In the ExactTarget Marketing Cloud using AMPSCripts and have not had any luck.

I was able to do this for the Portfolio folder by following the instructions from this link:
https://code.exacttarget.com/question/retrieve-all-contents-portfolio-folder

and thought I could use the same pattern for the My Contents folder but it is not working. Is there a specific way this needs to be done?

Comment: Would you mind adding your code here so we can try what you have ourselves? If it's long you can use something like codepen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked post essentially makes a WebService API call to retrieve the Portfolio object:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/portfolio/

The AMPScript just needs to be adjusted to look at the ContentArea Object and its relevant fields:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/contentarea/

```
List of Contents<br>
%%[
SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "ContentArea")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Name")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Content")   


SET @myConents= InvokeRetrieve(@rr)  

 FOR @c = 1 TO RowCount(@myConents)  DO    
 SET @currentContent = Row(@myConents,@c)   ]%%

Item: %%=v(@c)=%%<br>
Name: %%=v(Field(@currentContent ,'Name')  )=%% <br>
Content: %%=v(Field(@currentContent ,'Content')  )=%%<br>
<br>
%%[ NEXT @c ]%%
```

This also accesses content areas created in Template-based emails but not visible in the My Contents folder.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!