# Dynamic Image in Contact using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need help in displaying agent image in email signature. My current sendbale agent data extension only have values like FName, LName, Email. And all agent images are uploaded under Portfolio folder ET.

I am just wondering how do I match images with contact and then display in Email?

All agent images are saved as Fname_Lname.jpg. Any idea or code to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get inspiration from this question here: [Accessing the contents of My Contents folder using AMPScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40961/accessing-the-contents-of-my-contents-folder-using-ampscript)

However, depending on your setup, i would suggest that you simply include an image url in the data extension and then reference it from there.

If you are using marketing cloud connect, there are standard fields to pull the profile image from the user's profile inside sales/service cloud.

Alternatively, if you have given the images similar keys, you could build it out using the logic found here:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentimagebykey/

It could look something like this, assuming the fields are in your sendable DE and the right image external keys are present:

```
%%[
var @fname, @lname, @imageName, @defaultImage

set @fname = FName
set @lname = LName
set @imageName = Concat(@fname,"_",@lname)
set @defaultImage = "Default_ImageKey"


]%%
%%=ContentImagebyKey("@imageName","@defaultImage")=%%
```